# Writting a struct type in Hive from PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, parquet

I am trying to write a DF into hive :

```
df_block_identity.printSchema()

root
 |-- HUB_ID: long (nullable = false)
 |-- ClientId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- publicID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CreationAppSource: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LastUpdateAppSource: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FirstName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LastName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Email: string (nullable = true)
 |-- publicID_address: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CreationAppSource_address: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LastUpdateAppSource_address: string (nullable = true)
 |-- AddressNameDesc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- AddressObjective: string (nullable = true)
 |-- AddressQuality: string (nullable = true)
 |-- City: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Country: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ExtraData: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Region: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Street1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Street2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Street3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Street4: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ZipCode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- IsPrimaryAddress: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ExternalAddressID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- publicID_MOBILE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CreationAppSource_MOBILE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LastUpdateAppSource_MOBILE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- MOBILE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- publicID_FIXE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CreationAppSource_FIXE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LastUpdateAppSource_FIXE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FIXE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- service: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- publicID_Services: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- CreationAppSource_Services: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- LastUpdateAppSource_Services: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ServiceTypeId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ServiceId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ServiceStatus: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ActivationDate: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- DeactivationDate: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- publicID_Title: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CreationAppSource_Title: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LastUpdateAppSource_Title: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Title: string (nullable = true)
 |-- publicID_Civility: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CreationAppSource_Civility: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LastUpdateAppSource_Civility: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Civility: string (nullable = true)
 |-- publicID_Gender: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CreationAppSource_Gender: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LastUpdateAppSource_Gender: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Gender: string (nullable = true)
 |-- publicID_MaritalStatus: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CreationAppSource_MaritalStatus: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LastUpdateAppSource_MaritalStatus: string (nullable = true)
 |-- MaritalStatus: string (nullable = true)
 |-- publicID_BirthDate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CreationAppSource_BirthDate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LastUpdateAppSource_BirthDate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- BirthDate: date (nullable = true)
 |-- publicID_CSP: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CreationAppSource_CSP: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LastUpdateAppSource_CSP: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CSP: string (nullable = true)
 |-- publicID_NbChildren: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CreationAppSource_NbChildren: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LastUpdateAppSource_NbChildren: string (nullable = true)
 |-- NbChildren: string (nullable = true)
 |-- publicID_PMR: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CreationAppSource_PMR: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LastUpdateAppSource_PMR: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PMR: string (nullable = true)
 |-- publicID_DegreeDisability: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CreationAppSource_DegreeDisability: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LastUpdateAppSource_DegreeDisability: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DegreeDisability: string (nullable = true)
 |-- publicID_CompanyName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CreationAppSource_CompanyName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LastUpdateAppSource_CompanyName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CompanyName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- publicID_LanguageId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CreationAppSource_LanguageId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LastUpdateAppSource_LanguageId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LanguageId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- publicID_NationalityId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CreationAppSource_NationalityId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LastUpdateAppSource_NationalityId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- NationalityId: string (nullable = true)
```

sample data following this schema:

```
AHA d4cd8d01-6a4f-446c-838e-ded98c1e8d53    TOTO    TOTO    NULL    .   xxx@gmail.com   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    [{"publicID_Services":"d4cd8d01-6a4f-446c-838e-ded98c1e8d53","CreationAppSource_Services":"TOTO","LastUpdateAppSource_Services":"TOTO","ServiceTypeId":"OPTINS","ServiceId":"PARTENAIRES","ServiceStatus":true,"ActivationDate":"2015-09-18 00:00:00","DeactivationDate":"9999-12-31 23:59:59.999"},{"publicID_Services":"d4cd8d01-6a4f-446c-838e-ded98c1e8d53","CreationAppSource_Services":"TOTO","LastUpdateAppSource_Services":"TOTO","ServiceTypeId":"OPTINS","ServiceId":"NEWSLETTER","ServiceStatus":true,"ActivationDate":"2015-09-18 00:00:00","DeactivationDate":"9999-12-31 23:59:59.999"}]  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

I use the command : `df_block_identity.write.saveAsTable('sb_party_hub_dev.golden', mode='overwrite', format="parquet")`
This command finishes OK. I can see the table in Hive Metastore.

But when trying to request from hive with `select * from sb_party_hub_dev.golden`, i receive the error:

> java.io.IOException: org.apache.parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException:
>   Can not read value at 0 in block -1 in file
>   adl://home/hive/warehouse/sb_party_hub_dev.db/golden/part-r-00000-e3dcac27-021e-43e8-8687-01ae305d5b5d.snappy.parquet

When I remove the field `service` which is a array type, the `select` retrieves the content of the table.

What should I change, propably in my PySpark code, to write the table in Hive and be able to query it without error ?

---

EDIT:

I tried with another format : 
`df_block_identity.write.saveAsTable('sb_party_hub_dev.golden', mode='overwrite', format="orc")`

With this format, I can access my data through HIVE. Why is parquet failling then ?

Comment: Could you try the same column with backticks?

Comment: @Bala I am sorry, but I do not understand the question

Comment: Sometimes when reserved words are used as column names you will have to use backticks ```col``` to refer to that column.  How are you generating your DF?

Comment: @Bala you think that service is a reserved word and therefore i should not use it ?
My DF comes from JSON files.

Comment: Would be nice if you could update your post with some sample data and code till the point where you encounter issue.

Comment: @Bala That is exactly what i did for code. First I write, then I read - 2 command lines. Read the parquet format fails. Read the orc format works fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162521/discussion-between-steven-benet-and-bala).